# icon on the left side of table element rows?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a simple HTML table and I'm trying to add an icon on the left side of the row based on some conditional.  I tried doing `position: absolute;` on the icon but it still does not seem to show up.  Is this even possible to do considering the icon will be outside of the table itself?

Comment: When you added the position absolute, did you make sure that 1) the parent (row) had position: relative; and 2) you gave the icon any top/left/bottom/right positioning?

Comment: did you tried `float:left`?

Comment: you should add `position: relative`  to its container.

<td><img src="icon.png" /></td>

td should have position:relative and the img position absolute

Comment: I use a span as a wrapper and float right just change to float left https://yardpenalty.com/fantasy-football-ppr/#main

Comment: Do you guys use a different div inside the table?  It seems to remove it if it's not a td/th element.. I'm not sure where the icon should be placed with your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a narrow `td` just for it?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 20px;"><!-- icon here --><td>
        <td><!-- data --><td>
        <td><!-- data --><td>
        <td><!-- data --><td>
        <td><!-- data --><td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The width is optional but since you only have an icon in that column, you can keep its width small.

Comment: I tried this at first but it's very wonky with the sizing of the table.  I will resort to this if I can't see any other solution